# Making java applet online

Tags: java, web, applet, japplet, appletviewer

this is my first time posting here and i really need some help with my assignment,Thanks.

Firstly, I want to know what are the steps to access my java applet online and how do i modify my URL accordingly?.

Secondly, Currently i'm on the wait for a Helihost.org server, so how do i upload my files or applets to the server ? if that's the right way to ask the question .

P.S : If you can provide some really simple examples with the answer it'll be a GREAT help, if not it's okay.
Thank You.

Comment: You probably should post separate and a bit more detailed questions for those two points.

Comment: *"Secondly,.."* SO is a Q&A Site, not a help-desk or somewhere to find a tutor.  Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).

Answer (score 0):

**1- you need to create** html or jsp page that have an `applet` tag
which will load your applet, ex:

```
<applet code="my.package.name.myAppletClassName" archive="mysrcCodeJarFile.jar"></applet>
```

my.package.name.myAppletClassName is the packange name and class name of the applet

mysrcCodeJarFile.jar is the jar file that contains the applet among any other needed source code or resources. it should be placed properly next to jsp or html page, or use **relative path** in case jar file is in sub-folders or higher.

once thi is done, you can access your jsp page using your domain name and project name in web-server
ex: `http://www.myd omain.com/myapp/applet.jsp`

**2- you can upload your files** once you got the host info, you should get an **FTP** account info (username/ password and IP:Port) so you can use any ftp client and upload your files.

Comment: thanks for the reply. you explained some of the blury concepts i have but i still don't understand what i'm supposed to replace the  ".... /myapp/ ...." myapp part with

Comment: When u have a running server with a web sererver like tomcat. Then when u deploy app it will have a folder. That could be myapp or any other name